# Worker with Entity Framework repository base class

Tags: c#, entity-framework, backgroundworker

I would like to reuse the same base repository in ASP.NET Web API and also in a worker project. Of course in a worker we cannot use scoped services so need to make sure it is thread safe.

Is the example shown below thread safe to use when registering the context as a singleton?

Base repository class as shown (not whole class shown)

```
public class RepositoryBase<TContext> : IRepositoryBase<TContext> where TContext : DbContext, new()
{
    public Func<TContext> GetContext;

    public RepositoryBase()
    {
        GetContext = GetCurrentContext;
    }

    protected TContext GetCurrentContext()
    {
        return new TContext();
    }

    public IQueryable<TEntity> QueryAll<TEntity>() where TEntity : class
    {
        return GetDbSet<TEntity>().AsQueryable();
    }

    public void AddRange<TEntity>(IEnumerable<TEntity> entities) where TEntity : class
    {
        GetDbSet<TEntity>().AddRange(entities);
    }

    public async Task SaveChangesAsync()
    {
        await Context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
}
```

Here is my worker repository base class

```
public class WorkerRepositoryBase<TContext> : RepositoryBase<TContext>, IWorkerRepositoryBase<TContext> where TContext : DbContext, new()
{
    private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;

    public WorkerRepositoryBase(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
    }

    protected override TContext GetCurrentContext()
    {
        using var scope = _serviceProvider.CreateScope();
        return scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<TContext>();
    }
}
```

Comment: `GetContext()` achieves nothing, because  every time you instantiate `WorkerRepositoryBase<TContext>` a new scope is created.

Comment: If you want to create a scope from your worker, then you should probably use `IServiceProvider` directly, then resolve `WorkerRepositoryBase<TContext>` from the scope.

Comment: Maybe I can override the SaveAsync and GetDbSet and then use GetContext there instead?

Comment: No it's not safe, and this class is a major bug. There's no need for a "repository" CRUD class over a high-level Unit-of-Work like a DbContext, which means the code causes a ton of problems, including concurrency issues. Connections in general aren't thread safe and *DON'T* have to be.

Comment: A DbContext is a Unit-of-Work, not a database connection. Even connections are short-lived anyway, so it makes no sense to make either of them Singleton. Connection pooling ensures that closing and reopening a connection is cheap, so there's no reason to use a Singleton either.

Comment: Its fine if its registered as a scoped service @PanagiotisKanavos, trying to reuse other services which have this class as a dependency in the worker where it must be singleton

Comment: ASP.NET workers must be registered as singleton though? @PanagiotisKanavos

Comment: This is explained in the docs: [Use scoped services within a BackgroundService](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/scoped-service?pivots=dotnet-7-0). Inject `IServiceProvider` in the constructor and create your own scope when you need it with `using (IServiceScope scope = _serviceProvider.CreateScope())`. In that scope you can create services that only live in that scope

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, oh whoops not sure how it missed this!!!! Thank you!!

Comment: The problem isn't just thread safety. Since a DbContext is a Unit of Work, it keeps tracking all the objects it loads. That means that unless you dispose it, pending transactions will still be pending the next time you call `SaveChanges`. You may end up performing 5 pending DELETEs from a previous abandoned operation

Comment: made mistake with my original question and now uses what found in the docs, amended. this should now be okay as it uses seperate context fror every time savechanges is used? @PanagiotisKanavos

Answer (score 1):

Entity Framework Core, by default, is not thread-safe, so what you can do to improve this process is to use a per-request context, use a per-scope context in a Worker and ensure the correct elimination of the context, but your code is very good.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the silly question, I somehow missed that I CAN use scoped services in a worker.... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/scoped-service?pivots=dotnet-7-0.